# Div Borders Affecting Padding

Tags: html

I'm working on the links at the very top - when a link is clicked I change the class so that it is evident which page you're on.  I'm pretty sure it's the side and top borders that are causing this - to see it click on the 'contact' link and the links in between shift a few pixels to the side.  Also the selected link text is 1 or 2 pixels below the other.  Any suggestions?

It's not very noticeable, but I'm into the details at this point.

```
html,body{margin:0}

body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 140%;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #eee;
    }

div.content {
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left:200px;
    padding:15px;
    }

div.top-margin{
    height: 15px ;
    background-color:#000;
    }

div.top{
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #000;*/ 
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    }

div.left{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:770px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding-top:20px;
    }

div.body{
    height: 770px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;*/
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 90%;
    }

div.logo{
    height:125px;
    width:250px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

div.main{
    width: 1100px ;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    }

div.nav-links{
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  /*  margin-left:250px;*/
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    }

div.header-link{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 30px 0 0;
    }

 .logo-link{
    border-style: none;
    }

div#nav-links ul li {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:15px;
    /*border-bottom: dotted 1px black;*/

    }


ul#nav li.about-active {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:19px;
    /*border-bottom: solid 1px black;*/
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    background-color:white;

    }


ul#nav li.process-active {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:19px;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    background-color:white;

    }

ul#nav li.projects-active {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:19px;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    background-color:white;

    }

ul#nav li.contact-active {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:19px;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    background-color:white;

    }

ul#nav li.about {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:20px;

    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }

ul#nav li.process {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:20px;

    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }

ul#nav li.projects {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:20px;

    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }

ul#nav li.contact {
    /*width:110px;*/
    padding-right:20px;

    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }

    ul#nav li.filler-left { 
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    padding-left:311px;
    margin-left:210px;
    /*width:305px;*/

    }

    ul#nav li.filler {  
    padding-right:20px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    width:10%;
    }



ul#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

ul#nav a:hover {    
    text-decoration: none;
    color:blue;
    }

div.footer{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    }

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content=
    "HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org" />
    <meta name="generator" content="" />
    <title>
      NCB
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://joe-riggs.com/chip/style.css" />

  </head>
  <body> 
    <div class="top-margin"></div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://joe-riggs.com/chip"><img class="logo-link" src="http://joe-riggs.com/chip/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" height="125px" width="250px" /></a>

        </div>
        <div class="nav-links" id="nav-links">
          <ul id="nav">

            <li class="filler-left"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="about-active"><a href="http://joe-riggs.com/chip/">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="process"><a href="http://joe-riggs.com/chip/process">Process</a>

            </li>
            <li class="projects"><a href="http://joe-riggs.com/chip/projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="http://joe-riggs.com/chip/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filler"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <li>Links</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">

      <img src="images/architect.png" alt="me" style="float:left; padding-right:10px;" />
       So this is the main page - the first page people will see when they come
       to your page.  Maybe we could put a nifty pic of you doing something
       architect looking.  Also a general overview would be nice.  This text
       can go over top of a faded background picture too.
       <br />
      <br />
        Donec velit nibh, pellentesque in fringilla a, blandit id nibh. Class
        aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos. Nam posuere mattis velit eget rhoncus. Maecenas
        bibendum tristique dolor, nec varius nulla porta eget. Aenean turpis
        ligula, ornare in consectetur vitae, aliquet id nulla. Vivamus bibendum
        sapien id neque lacinia vel viverra ante luctus. Sed lacinia velit id
        diam vulputate sollicitudin. Integer viverra libero vel enim dapibus
        rutrum. Praesent vel ipsum tortor. Pellentesque porttitor ante sed
        felis pretium nec rhoncus eros lacinia. Nam a massa nec sapien eleifend
        condimentum. Fusce ut augue id libero condimentum facilisis.<br />
        <br />
        Donec metus turpis, aliquet euismod tempor ut, vehicula condimentum
        odio. Morbi vulputate imperdiet nibh et porta. Etiam et nulla est, ut
        rhoncus nisi. Mauris eleifend lectus nunc, eu elementum odio. Aliquam
        erat volutpat. Morbi et dolor sit amet enim malesuada pretium sed quis
        odio. Vivamus convallis aliquam massa, blandit vehicula justo consequat
        in. Sed imperdiet rutrum volutpat. Nunc dignissim aliquet mattis. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu quam,
        euismod ut porttitor non, lobortis vitae massa. Aliquam venenatis purus
        id mauris consequat vel luctus quam vulputate. Duis in neque libero.
        Aenean pretium pharetra justo vel dapibus. Donec risus felis, facilisis
        in vestibulum sit amet, tincidunt sit amet tellus. Donec ullamcorper
        euismod lacus id pulvinar.<br />
        <br />

        Donec metus turpis, aliquet euismod tempor ut, vehicula condimentum
        odio. Morbi vulputate imperdiet nibh et porta. Etiam et nulla est, ut
        rhoncus nisi. Mauris eleifend lectus nunc, eu elementum odio. Aliquam
        erat volutpat. Morbi et dolor sit amet enim malesuada pretium sed quis
        odio. Vivamus convallis aliquam massa, blandit vehicula justo consequat
        in. Sed imperdiet rutrum volutpat. Nunc dignissim aliquet mattis. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu quam,
        euismod ut porttitor non, lobortis vitae massa. Aliquam venenatis purus
        id mauris consequat vel luctus quam vulputate. Duis in neque libero.
        Aenean pretium pharetra justo vel dapibus. Donec risus felis, facilisis
        in vestibulum sit amet, tincidunt sit amet tellus. Donec ullamcorper
        euismod lacus id pulvinar.
      </div>
    <div class="footer">
    <br />
    copyright &copy; 2010
    </div>
    </div><!--main-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way you can post the relevant markup here? Otherwise, as soon as you fix the issue this question becomes completely useless to anyone else that finds it during a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you add:

border-top: solid 1px #FFF;
border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
border-left: solid 1px #FFF;

to your ' div#nav-links ul li ' class, it may fix the issue. The problem arises because you add a 1px border to the selected li which will push the other tabs over 1px. If they already have a 1px border, all you're doing is changing the color.

Comment: thanks, this got my vertical alignment - cant use borders all around links because it will put gaps in the black line elsewhere-

Comment: `1px solid transparent` may be cleaner if it doesn't have to work in ie6.

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like the issue is due to the borders (top when selected, and bottom when not selected). Borders actually affect the height/width of elements on a page.

I would recommend keeping the 1px solid border on all sides, but simply change the color to make them "visible" or not. That way their positioning doesn't change based on selection.

You can see how to have different colors on different border sides via [W3Schools CSS Border Colors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-color.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; it is because of the borders. You must adjust the padding/margins or width/height of the selected tab to compensate.